# Use regexp to get value of input

Tags: javascript, regex, input

in my page I have some inputs button written in this way:

```
<input type="button" value="" idtag="" style="color:rgb(51, 156, 203); background-color:white; border:0px; padding:0px;">
```

Can I use the regexp to get the value of value and of idtag?  And after the method replace, to replace the result on string?

```
text = text.replace(/(<input type="button" value="(.+)" idtag="(.+)" style="color:rgb(51, 156, 203); background-color:white; border:0px; padding:0px;"> )/gi, function($0,$1,$2){return $3+"-"+$4;});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

They are attributes of a DOM object, so you can retrieve them like this:

```
var button = ...;

var idtag = button['idtag'];
var value = button['value'];
```

Comment: Can I use this solution if the input code is included inside  other HTML code?

Comment: what do you mean? if it is included as data and not HTML?